# jupyter notebook pyinstaller exe failes to read a file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyinstaller

So I have written a python script using the anaconda / jupyter notebook.
 The script when run in this environment it all ok.
 I would then copy the script and paste it to a file, saving it with a .py extension.
 Then, from the command prompt i run:

```
pyinstaller -w -F myProgram.py
```

However, the .exe file does not seem to behave the same as the script when run from the jupyter notebook.
  After some troubleshooting i found out that the below is where the issue is caused.
  The file I'm reading has some special characters (cubed symbol).

```
for line in open(os.path.join(AMSFiles, file), "r"):
    XMLFile.append(line)
```

After changing the code to the below, now the .exe works as well.

```
for line in open(os.path.join(AMSFiles, file), "rb"):
    XMLFile.append(line.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
```

My question is, why can I run the first lines of code in jupyter notebook without any error buts not its resultant .exe? I would expect the special character to give an error in both instances, what is different?

Regards,

Comment: You are disabling console output with `-w` flag and that is why you don't get any errors in the console. Try to remove the flag and try again.

Comment: Hi MR, I meant that the script runs fine in jupyter (this is before running the pyinstaller with the -w flag). Then when I convert the script into an .exe file, it faults on some special characters. I'm not sure why there is a difference in behavior even though it is the same script? The lines in question are the first two lines I mentioned:

    **for line in open(os.path.join(AMSFiles, file), "r"):'
        'XMLFile.append(line)'**

Comment: Run your code as I said and put the exact error.

Comment: Hi MR, thanks, I've now learnt a better practice. On the issue itself though, it seems that now I cannot reproduce it, strange :S